# How can you check if "public user registration" is turned on or off on the front-end?

Tags: users, user-profile, registration

I'm trying to make a rather bullet proof front-end template that can toggle a sign up link based on if [public registration](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/users#public-registration) is enabled or not.

Is there a way I can query to see if the system currently has [public registration](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/users#public-registration) turned `on` from the front-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that has a [Template Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) that exposes Craft's [SystemSettingsService->getSettings()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/SystemSettingsService#getSetting-detail) method like so:

```
public function isPublicRegistrationEnabled()
{
    return craft()->systemSettings->getSetting('users', 'allowPublicRegistration');
}
```

You'd call it from the template via:

```
{% if craft.myAwesomePlugin.isPublicRegistrationEnabled() %}
    Enabled!
{% endif %}
```